# Installed chrome driver and added it to path yet error shows Chromedriver needs to be in path

Tags: python, selenium, chrome-web-driver

hey guys so im trying to make a Chegg bot which needs the chromedriver and
I downloaded the chrome webdriver and imported selenium using my command line. i added the webdriver in path and I specified the location yet weeoes show that the file cannot be located and that the chromedriver needs to be in path

if anyone needs more information ill be glad to provide, I would greatly appreciate is someone tried to test the code out for me, just let me know so I can share it on github

subprocess.py

```
self._execute_child(args, executable, preexec_fn, close_fds,
                                pass_fds, cwd, env,
                                startupinfo, creationflags, shell,
                                p2cread, p2cwrite,
                                c2pread, c2pwrite,
                                errread, errwrite,
                                restore_signals, start_new_session)

 hp, ht, pid, tid = _winapi.CreateProcess(executable, args,
                                         # no special security
                                         None, None,
                                         int(not close_fds),
                                         creationflags,
                                         env,
                                         cwd,
                                         startupinfo)
```

service.py

```
self.process = subprocess.Popen(cmd, env=self.env,
                                            close_fds=platform.system() != 'Windows',
                                            stdout=self.log_file,
                                            stderr=self.log_file,
                                            stdin=PIPE) 


raise WebDriverException(
                    "'%s' executable needs to be in PATH. %s" % (
                        os.path.basename(self.path), self.start_error_message
```

Webdriver.py

```
  self.service = Service(
            executable_path,
            port=port,
            service_args=service_args,
            log_path=service_log_path)
        self.service.start()
```

Davids_Chegg.py

```
chrome_driver = r'C:\Webdrivers\chromedriver.exe\'

if __name__ == '__main__':
    browser = webdriver.Chrome("C:\Webdrivers\chromedriver.exe")
    signin()
    client.run(bot_token)
    # test comment
```

```
ERRORS:

Traceback (most recent call last):
  File "C:\Python38\lib\site-packages\selenium\webdriver\common\service.py", line 72, in start
    self.process = subprocess.Popen(cmd, env=self.env,
  File "C:\Python38\lib\subprocess.py", line 854, in __init__
    self._execute_child(args, executable, preexec_fn, close_fds,
  File "C:\Python38\lib\subprocess.py", line 1307, in _execute_child
    hp, ht, pid, tid = _winapi.CreateProcess(executable, args,
FileNotFoundError: [WinError 2] The system cannot find the file specified

During handling of the above exception, another exception occurred:

Traceback (most recent call last):
  File "c:\Users\david\Desktop\Python\chegg_bot\David_s Chegg.py", line 282, in <module>
    browser = webdriver.Chrome(executable_path="chromedriver", options=opts)
  File "C:\Python38\lib\site-packages\selenium\webdriver\chrome\webdriver.py", line 73, in __init__
    self.service.start()
  File "C:\Python38\lib\site-packages\selenium\webdriver\common\service.py", line 81, in start
    raise WebDriverException(
selenium.common.exceptions.WebDriverException: Message: 'chromedriver' executable needs to be in PATH. Please see https://sites.google.com/a/chromium.org/chromedriver/home
```

Answer (score 0):

You can try the code below and you don't need to worry about the path setting or webdriver installation according to the web browser version.

Just install webdriver_manager to use this code using a command: `pip install webdriver_manager`

```
from selenium import webdriver
from webdriver_manager.chrome import ChromeDriverManager

driver = webdriver.Chrome(ChromeDriverManager().install())
```

I am using this for web scraping and it works perfectly.

Answer (score 0):

Steps to follow

1. Go to Local c and find the Python file directory
2. And paste the Drive executable file in the Python folder
3. Run again the script

It will work 100%